# Finding rows with random english words in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a table which has rows with random English words combined with numbers like

```
123-Bay1
==============
2-Exit
==============
Entrance-7
==============
Adams Shop #1
==============
Garden Center
==============
WM-9999
==============
90TS8999
==============
90998788
---------------
```

How can we NOT select the rows having English words? please note the words are very random, these are some of the examples.

Below should be the result

```
WM-9999
-------------
90TS8999
-------------
90998788
------------
```

Comment: Do you have a source of "English" words?

Comment: no there is no source, it can be anything

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to better specify the problem.  "English word" is rather indeterminate.  And if it had words like "fait accompli" or "shadenfreude", would you reject that because they are really more French or German than English?

I would suggest other patterns.  For instance, your desired rows have at least four digits in a row, so you could use:

```
where col like '%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%'
```

Or they end with two or more digits:

```
where col like '%[0-9][0-9]'
```

Or, they have no vowels:

```
where col not like '%[AEIOU]%'
```

Or, perhaps there is some other pattern better than "English word".